GWR on spatially joined attributes
I am new here and am trying to build and compare a couple models using spatial data for estimation (GLM and GWR). I am trying to estimate counts using a training dataset that contains observations on randomly located points across the study area. At the moment, I am using three independent variables with metrics that describe the counting points.
On the other hand, I have some aggregated census attributes that I could assign (join) to the points based on the census area.
Here is my question, would it be appropriate to use a GWR model in this case?
I am new to spatial statistics. I understand that the predictive capabilities of GWR are limited. Am I correct? I would appreciate some guidance.
Thanks for your time.
